# Angularjs register form not working

Tags: html, angularjs

I have Angular App, and there is a register form like(Contact-Page with add user) below, but not binding data means (ADD Delete User not working) just displaying the form. Does anyone know how to do it?

View: contact.html

```
  <div class="generic-container" ng-controller="RegCtrl as ctrl">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><span class="lead">User Registration Form </span></div>
 <div class="formcontainer">
   <form ng-submit="ctrl.submit()" name="myForm" class="form-horizontal">
     <input type="hidden" ng-model="ctrl.user.id" />
     <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-lable" for="file">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.username" name="uname" class="username form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter your name" required ng-minlength="3"/>
          <div class="has-error" ng-show="myForm.$dirty">
            <span ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.required">This is a required field</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.minlength">Minimum length required is 3</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.uname.$invalid">This field is invalid </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-lable" for="file">Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.address" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter your Address. [This field is validation free]"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-lable" for="file">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="email" ng-model="ctrl.user.email" name="email" class="email form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter your Email" required/>
          <div class="has-error" ng-show="myForm.$dirty">
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">This is a required field</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$invalid">This field is invalid </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="row">
      <div class="form-actions floatRight">
        <input type="submit"  value="{{!ctrl.user.id ? 'Add' : 'Update'}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
        <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.reset()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine">Reset Form</button>
      </div>
     </div>
   </form>
 </div>
 </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
     <!-- Default panel contents -->
   <div class="panel-heading"><span class="lead">List of Users </span></div>
   <div class="tablecontainer">
     <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>ID.</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th width="100">
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="u in ctrl.users">
      <td><span ng-bind="u.id"></span></td>
      <td><span ng-bind="u.username"></span></td>
      <td><span ng-bind="u.address"></span></td>
      <td><span ng-bind="u.email"></span></td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.edit(u.id)" class="btn btn-success custom-width">Edit</button>  <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.remove(u.id)" class="btn btn-danger custom-width">Remove</button>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Contrller:

```
            angular.module('myApp', [])
            .controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            var self = this;
            self.user={id:null,username:'',address:'',email:''};
            self.id = 4;

            self.users = [// In future posts, we will get it from server using service
                {id:1, username: 'Sam', address: 'NY', email: 'sam@abc.com'},
                {id:2, username: 'Tomy', address: 'ALBAMA', email: 'tomy@abc.com'},
                {id:3, username: 'kelly', address: 'NEBRASKA', email: 'kelly@abc.com'}
            ];

            self.submit = function() {
                if(self.user.id==null){
                    self.user.id = self.id++;
                    console.log('Saving New User', self.user);
                    self.users.push(self.user);//Or send to server, we will do it in when handling services
                }else{
                    for(var i = 0; i < self.users.length; i++){
                        if(self.users[i].id == self.user.id) {
                            self.users[i] = self.user;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    console.log('User updated with id ', self.user.id);
                }
                self.reset();
            };

            self.edit = function(id){
                console.log('id to be edited', id);
                for(var i = 0; i < self.users.length; i++){
                    if(self.users[i].id == id) {
                        self.user = angular.copy(self.users[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            self.remove = function(id){
                console.log('id to be deleted', id);
                for(var i = 0; i < self.users.length; i++){
                    if(self.users[i].id == id) {
                        self.users.splice(i,1);
                        if(self.user.id==id){//It is shown in form, reset it.
                            self.reset();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            self.reset = function(){
                self.user={id:null,username:'',address:'',email:''};
                $scope.myForm.$setPristine(); //reset Form
            }

        }]);
```

app.js

```
                 'use strict';

                /**
                * @ngdoc overview
                * @name peopleApp
                * @description
                * # myApp
                *
               * Main module of the application.
             */
               angular
               .module('myApp', [
                 'ngAnimate',
                 'ngCookies',
                 'ngResource',
                  'ngRoute',
                  'ngSanitize',
                   'ngTouch'
                   ])
             .config(function ($routeProvider) {
               $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'main'
                })
                .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'CarouselDemoCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'main'
                 })
                .when('/Portfolio', {
                templateUrl: 'views/Portfolio.html',
                controller: 'ctrlApp',
                controllerAs: 'Portfolio'
                })
               .when('/photos', {
               templateUrl: 'views/photos.html',
               controller: 'AlbumCtrl',
               controllerAs: 'photos'
               })
              .when('/tour', {
               templateUrl: 'views/tour.html',
               controller: 'ctrlTags',
               controllerAs: 'tour'
               })

              .when('/about', {
              templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
              controller: 'AboutCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'about'
               })
             .when('/myganesha', {
             templateUrl: 'views/myganesha.html',
             controller: 'frmController',
             controllerAs: 'myganesha'
             })
            .when('/contact', {
             templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
             controller: 'RegCtrl',
             controllerAs: 'contact'
             })
            .when('/login', {
             templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
             controller: 'loginCtrl',
             controllerAs: 'login'
             })
            .when('/help', {
             templateUrl: 'views/help.html',
             controller: 'DefaultController',
             controllerAs: 'help'
             })
            .otherwise({
             redirectTo: '/'
               });
            });
```

Comment: hi Anand any idea about my requirement as i mension above , how to implement it ? can you help me?

Comment: You can't just ask "How do I do this?". Your question should include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So, why not adding a demo (jsFiddle, Plunkr, etc). That would increase your chances to get a good answer.

Comment: Hey U r s u s i am new to angularjs and please help me to solve this.